# how to place image behind navbar dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
    const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");



    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // toggle nav
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

        // animate links
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = '';
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
            }
        });
        // burger animation
        burger.classList.toggle("toggle")

    });
}

navSlide();
```

```css
/* global */
* {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* navbar */
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: #5d4954;
}

.logo   {
    color: rgb(181, 181, 181);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
    color: rgb(181, 181, 181); 
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{
width: 25px;
height: 2px;
background-color: rgb(181, 181, 181);
margin: 5px;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .nav-links{
        width: 60%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: #5d4954;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
    }
}
.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%)
}
@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from{
opacity: 0;
transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to{
opacity: 1;
transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.toggle .line1{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,5px);
}
.toggle .line2{
    opacity: 0;
}
.toggle .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-5px);
}

/* header */
header {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.containerBox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.text-box {
    position: absolute;    
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;    
    width: 100%;
}
.text-box:before {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.text-box h4 {
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 30px;
   color: #3c4245;   
   letter-spacing: 5px;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h4>Gunnar</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>

    </nav>
    <header>
        <div class="containerBox">
            <div class="text-box">
                <h4>Software Engineer | UX/UI Design</h4>
            </div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="./images/header.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: use jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: here is the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/GunnarHudson/rgvfzkeb/2/)

Comment: Fiddler is missing your HTML

Comment: Where do you want your image to be displayed? your images don't show a submenu

Comment: apolgize for all the confusions, learning fiddle and stack overflow. fixed now with html @AdamH and image is local so it wont show, but looking to be under hamburger menu. When i expand it, it goes behind the image i placed

Comment: Hey @GunnarHudson maybe take a quick read about [stack snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and post your code as a snippet. There is an issue with your fiddler link an the image isn't code.

Comment: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/GunnarHudson/rgvfzkeb/12/)

Comment: For fiddle use - Top Left = HTML; Top Right = CSS, Bottom Left = JavaScript. All of that is combined and injected into the Bottom Right (result). Your fiddle doesn't have HTML so there is nothing but JavaScript in the result window and therefore nothing for us to look at.

Comment: okay, idk why it had so many issues with me pasting in my html. but its fixed as far as i know.

Comment: [fiddle link fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/GunnarHudson/rgvfzkeb/13/)

Comment: @AdamH sorry about the n00bery, since my image is local it won't show, however in the OP i added a photo of whats happening.

Comment: I just edited your post to use a snippet however it is still unclear exactly what you are looking for. Where do you want this image to be displayed?

Comment: so in the image i posted in the original post, the drop down goes behind the image used, but im looking to have it drop in front. the image covers about 30% of what the nav dropdown actually shows. does that help at all?

Comment: [gif of issue](https://gph.is/g/aQWeoVA)

Comment: Add some context to the question. It's just code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the absolute positioning on the `.nav-links` class inside the media query. Setting the z-index addresses the issue however isn't exactly the best way to approach this problem. Here is a fixed up version:

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
  const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");



  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // toggle nav
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    // animate links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = '';
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
      }
    });
    // burger animation
    burger.classList.toggle("toggle")

  });
}

navSlide();
```

```css
/* global */

* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* navbar */

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: #5d4954;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(181, 181, 181);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(181, 181, 181);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(181, 181, 181);
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #5d4954;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%)
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 5px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -5px);
}


/* header */

header {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.containerBox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-box:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-box h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #3c4245;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <h4>Gunnar</h4>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>

</nav>
<header>
  <div class="containerBox">
    <div class="text-box">
      <h4>Software Engineer | UX/UI Design</h4>
    </div>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.imgur.com/dc1PU8j.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: it worked! not exactly sure where the fix was however. Which file(s) were edited?